# obj1 contained in obj2 as array and obj2 as array in obj3, obj1 has a static variable

Tags: c++

```
struct obj1
{
    static int counter = 0;
    obj1() {counter++;}
};

struct obj2
{
    obj1* o1 = nullptr;
};

struct obj3
{
    obj2* o2 = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    obj3 o3;
    o3.o2 = new obj2[3];
    o3.o2[0].o1 = new obj1[1];
    o3.o2[1].o1 = new obj1[4];
    o3.o2[2].o1 = new obj1[3];
}
```

Does every array of o1 has it's own static counter or all the objects o1 share the same counter? and why?

Comment: for o3.o2[0] = new o1[1] the counter will be 1
for o3.o2[1] = new o1[4] the counter will be 4
for o3.o2[2] = new o1[3] the counter will be 3

or the counter will be 8 in general?

Comment: Why you are using `new` in 1st place? You should rather use something like `std:vector<obj1> o1;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define class members static using **static** keyword. When we declare a member of a class as static it means no matter how many objects of the class are created, there is only one copy of the static member.

A static member is shared by all objects of the class. All static data is initialized to zero when the first object is created, if no other initialization is present. We can't put it in the class definition but it can be initialized outside the class as done in the following example by redeclaring the static variable, using the scope resolution operator :: to identify which class it belongs to.

Let us try the following example to understand the concept of static data members:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box
{
   public:
      static int objectCount;
      // Constructor definition
      Box(double l=2.0, double b=2.0, double h=2.0)
      {
         cout <<"Constructor called." << endl;
         length = l;
         breadth = b;
         height = h;
         // Increase every time object is created
         objectCount++;
      }
      double Volume()
      {
         return length * breadth * height;
      }
   private:
      double length;     // Length of a box
      double breadth;    // Breadth of a box
      double height;     // Height of a box
};

// Initialize static member of class Box
int Box::objectCount = 0;

int main(void)
{
   Box Box1(3.3, 1.2, 1.5);    // Declare box1
   Box Box2(8.5, 6.0, 2.0);    // Declare box2

   // Print total number of objects.
   cout << "Total objects: " << Box::objectCount << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

When the above code is compiled and executed, it produces the following result:

```
Constructor called.
Constructor called.
Total objects: 2
```

Because of this the `static` counter is the same for all the `o1` objects

Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I know that. I'm asking box class was contained as an array in class obj1, and obj1 was contained as an array in obj2 class. If I'll open an array of obj1, and each obj1 objects has an array of boxes, is the static objectCount still be shared by all obj1's objects or for each obj1 in the array I'll have a different shared objectCout? I hope you understand my question.

Comment: No problem.  Answering your question, the concept here is the same.  You will have one class and multiple instances.  All the `o1` objects will share the same counter.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a single variable. You will have to have in your program somewhere:

```
int obj1::counter;
```

which is the definition of that variable. (The in-class declaration is only a declaration).

As to "why", that's what `static` means here. There's no language construct for having a variable that is shared amongst objects but only ones that are a member of an array. If that's what you want then you would have to explicitly make a class that contains an array and the variable, or whatever.

If you just want to keep track of how many items are in the array then use a container like `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of a raw pointer.